# How to interact with website from android app

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, jsoup, httpurlconnection, robotium

I am trying to interact with a website from an android application. More specifically I am trying to login to my online depot and retrieve different data like balances, profit/loss on current day and so on because I don't want to log on to the webpage manually every time I want to see how my stocks are doing. Unfortunately my bank does not have an android app for those purposes.

What I want is an app that automatically retrieves the information from the website and shows it as an notification. So I need to open the website, login with username, password and cookie and then find specific elements (e.g. by css selector).

So far I only achieved something similar with selenium webdriver on windows. Since selenium does not run on android I have to find another solution.

What I have look into so far:

HTMLUnit (not running on android)

HttpURLConnection + JSoup (not sure if this allows me to simulate clicks on specific buttons...)

Robotium (can it only be used for testing apps or also for my purposes?)

Are there alternatives? Can this be achieved with one of the listed tools?

Any ideas are appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Why don't you code a webservice on your server and let it communicate with the application

Comment: This is definitely and option but I would like to achieve it without an extra server running.

Comment: It is not an extra server,but some extra code inside your web site,and which will be easier and faster than what you have now

Comment: The problem is that I don't have access to the web site and can't modify it. It is the following page: https://webtrading.onvista-bank.de